# Как сделать такую карточку товара? На чистом CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: Карточка][image: Карточка товара]

Интересует сделать такую карточку товара, но не понимаю как именно это работает, также указываю ссылку на макет фигмы [вот она](https://www.figma.com/file/PtLRa4rz5WvS6ZSTNRZfuk/Freebie_Coffee-Copy?node-id=0%3A1)
Помогите пж кодом)

У меня получилось сделать вертикальную зеленую карточку, но горизонтальную не выходит, и проблема с текстом внутри у меня, хелп ^_^

Comment: Вы сами что то делали? Обучение не входит в тематику stackoverflow, здесь помогают и даже делают иногда с ноля но когда вопрос интересный

Comment: В том то и дело что пытался, но не вышло, и зашел сюда попросить помощи.

Comment: флекс контейнер и два дива внутри, не?

Comment: Если пытались сами, то лучше приложите свою попытку.

Answer (score 4):

Задача типична, как говорится рутина

1. смотрим размеры и устанавливаем шрифты и так же обнуляем отступы и главного документа
2. Картинки - создаём рядом с index.html папку с именем img/images/i как угодно, если когда то у вас зайдёт речь о вёрстке под cms то там будет ограничение для имени этой папки и все картинки из figma складываем в эту папку

Я сделал просто так - использовал flexbox и для мануала покурите вот это : [webref.ru](https://webref.ru/layout/visual-guide-flexbox) и согласно  инструкции на этом сайте мы укажем для родителя всех карточек: `display: flex;`

В общем смотрите и если вдруг что то станет не ясно - переспросите комментариями

**Внимание - не адаптивно**

> javascript применил так как лень кучу раз писать src для картинок и
> так же кучу раз вставлять один и тот же текст -

Здесь чуть чуть модернизировал: [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/wvzZMad?editors=1000)

```js
let text = "Парикмахерское кресло НОРМ гидровлическое";
let price = "9900 &#8381;";

document.querySelectorAll(".description").forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = text;
});

document.querySelectorAll(".price").forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = price;
});

document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(function(img) {
  img.src =
    "https://tua-vita.ru/upload/iblock/851/851fadff5982b69c94f3097c8630ada4.png";
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

.cart {
  width: 180px;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.cart:not(:first-child) {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.price {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.button {
  margin: 20px auto;
}

.button button {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #66c05d;
  border-radius: 30px;
  transition: scale 0.1s ease-in;
  color: #fff;
}

.button:hover button {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #48983e;
}
```

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="flex">

    <div class="cart">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price"></div>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button"> Купить</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price"></div>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button"> Купить</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price"></div>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button"> Купить</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="cart">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="price"></div>
      <div class="button">
        <button type="button"> Купить</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант

```css
p, h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

.card {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  font-family: Nunito, sans-serif;
  width: 560px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.05), 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
}

.img-wrap {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}

.content-wrap {
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.price  {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 5;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: #C7A17A;
}

.title {
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 28px;
  color: #232C38;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.description {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #151D28;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.toggle-wrap {
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.toggle-buy,
.toggle-info {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
}


.toggle-buy {
  display: block;
  width: 134px;
  background: #C7A17A;
  border-radius: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #F9FBFF;
}

.toggle-info {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 29px;
  color: #415167;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="img-wrap">
    <img height="256" width="256" src="" alt="picture">
  </div>
  <div class="content-wrap">
    <p class="price">99.000</p>
    <h3 class="title">REVO Morning</h3>
    <p class="description">đắng, hậu ngọt, hương hoa </p>
    <div class="toggle-wrap">
      <a class="toggle-buy" href="#">MUA NGAY</a>
      <a class="toggle-info" href="#">CHI TIẾT</a>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```